# Strange anomalies with font awesome sass rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

As you can see below I have clearly attempted to use the icon with class user-md, but this has somehow shown up as an ubuntu icon. I'm very very confused.

[image]

Also, another anomaly... I have a nav list as described on twitter bootstrap... http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

For some reason the active li shows the overlay of icon-glass .. over the desired icon-home. The normal li shows just the house.

[image]

I am using ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME Shell 3.6.2 and here is my gemfile lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    RedCloth (4.2.9)
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    active_enum (0.9.12)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    annotate (2.4.1.beta1)
    arel (3.0.2)
    awesome_print (1.1.0)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    better_errors (0.3.2)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.7.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.6.8)
    blankslate (3.1.2)
    bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    cocaine (0.4.2)
    coderay (1.0.8)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    country_select (1.1.3)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    debugger (1.2.4)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.1.1)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.1.7)
    debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (>= 1.1.1)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.7)
    devise (2.2.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
      sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)
    forem-redcarpet (1.0.0)
      pygments.rb (= 0.2.4)
      redcarpet (= 2.0.1)
    geocoder (1.1.6)
    gmaps4rails (1.5.6)
    gon (4.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 2.3.0)
      json
    google_visualr (2.1.5)
    googlecharts (1.6.8)
    guard (1.6.1)
      listen (>= 0.6.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (2.4.0)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.11)
    haml (3.1.7)
    hash-deep-merge (0.1.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (3.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.7.6)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    lazy_high_charts (1.3.2)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      hash-deep-merge
    libnotify (0.8.0)
      ffi (>= 1.0.11)
    listen (0.7.2)
    lumberjack (1.0.2)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.0)
      rack-contrib
      rails
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    nested_form (0.3.1)
    nifty-generators (0.4.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.11.3)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-debugger (0.2.1)
      debugger (~> 1.2.0)
      pry (~> 0.9.10)
    pygments.rb (0.2.4)
      rubypython (~> 0.5.3)
    quiet_assets (1.0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
    rack (1.4.4)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-pjax (0.7.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.3)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    rails_admin (0.4.1)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1)
      font-awesome-sass-rails (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0.1)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      jquery-rails (~> 2.1)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 3.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.2)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.6)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (2.0.1)
    remotipart (1.0.2)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rolify (3.2.0)
    rspec (2.12.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.12.0)
    rspec-core (2.12.2)
    rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.12.1)
    rspec-rails (2.12.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.12.0)
    rubypython (0.5.3)
      blankslate (>= 2.1.2.3)
      ffi (~> 1.0.7)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sequel (3.20.0)
    simple_form (2.0.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    slop (3.4.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    squeel (1.0.14)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    taps (0.3.24)
      rack (>= 1.0.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
      sequel (~> 3.20.0)
      sinatra (~> 1.0.0)
    thin (1.5.0)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)
    workflow (0.8.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven no idea what's going on with an Ubuntu icon. Very strange.

The second issue is a bit easier. It's fixed in 3.0.2, the latest Font Awesome, which it appears the Gem you're using isn't updated yet.

Try calling Font Awesome and Bootstrap from the Bootstrap CDN into your HTML: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome

-Dave

Font Awesome Creator & Maintainer

Comment: Dave, thanks for your help. I really can't explain what happened there either.. what I ended up doing was removing @import 'font-awesome' from my application.css file, loading the site, and the re-adding it. I can't really explain why that fixed it, but it's fixed. I cleared the browser cache before and that wasn't it, so it must have been a rails thing. Thanks again.